# What's $0 in nginx? (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying convert my Apache rewrite rules for my new nginx webserver, but I'm having problems translating this particular line:

`RewriteRule      ^(arin|barry|john|ross|danny).*$   /share/$0 [NC]`

As for my old Apache server, this rule caused

`http://example.com/danny/awesomeVideo.avi` to view `http://example.com/share/danny/awesomeVideo.avi` instead, without the link changing.

To be honest, as my Apache setup was a long time ago, I'm not even sure whether or not the link *not* changing in the address bar for someone who views the file was due to this rule or not.

Most online converters will propose this rule for nginx:

`rewrite ^/(arin|barry|john|ross|danny).*$ /share/$0 last;`

Unfortunately, `$0` seems to be faulty, as this is what I get when restarting nginx:

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] **unknown "0" variable**
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Does anyone know how to express Apache's `$0` in nginx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use `$uri` or `$request_uri` instead `$0`